# Оставить только те элементы которые удовлетворяют условию

Tags: jquery

Создать новый набор только тех элементы разметки которые удовлетворяют условию, что дочерний input > 0, т.е. оставить только тех родителей с классом "col- " у которых дочерний input больше 0.

```js
$('#account_calcLayoutGrid12 .row ').find('[class^="col-"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account_calcLayoutGrid12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage2">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage2" alt="" title="Заголовок1">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText19">
        <span id="wb_uid23">Текст1</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox1" name="dop1" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText23">
        <span id="wb_uid24"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage3">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage3" alt="" title="Заголовок2">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText20">
        <span id="wb_uid25">Текст2</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox2" name="dop2" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText24">
        <span id="wb_uid26"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage7">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage7" alt="" title="Заголовок3">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText21">
        <span>Текст3</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox4" name="dop3" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText25">
        <span id="wb_uid30"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage6">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage6" alt="" title="Заголовок4">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText22">
        <span id="wb_uid31">Текст4</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox5" name="dop4" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText26">
        <span id="wb_uid32"><strong><em><span class="priceDop">0</span> руб.</em>
        </strong>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не советую использовать `console` на весь объект, этот сниппет не любит это и бывает даже ложит страницу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
$('#www').on('click', function() {
  $('#account_calcLayoutGrid12 .row ').find('[class^="col-"]').each(function() {
    let inputVal = $(this).find('input[type="number"]').val();
    if (inputVal > 0) {
      console.info($(this).attr('class') + ' имеет input со значением > 0');
      $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account_calcLayoutGrid12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage2">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage2" alt="" title="Заголовок1">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText19">
        <span id="wb_uid23">Текст1</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox1" name="dop1" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText23">
        <span id="wb_uid24"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage3">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage3" alt="" title="Заголовок2">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText20">
        <span id="wb_uid25">Текст2</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox2" name="dop2" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText24">
        <span id="wb_uid26"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage7">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage7" alt="" title="Заголовок3">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText21">
        <span>Текст3</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox4" name="dop3" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText25">
        <span id="wb_uid30"><strong><em>0 руб.</em></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="wb_account_calcImage6">
        <img src="" id="account_calcImage6" alt="" title="Заголовок4">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_account_calcText22">
        <span id="wb_uid31">Текст4</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" id="account_calcEditbox5" name="dop4" value="0" spellcheck="false">
      <div id="wb_account_calcText26">
        <span id="wb_uid32"><strong><em><span class="priceDop">0</span> руб.</em>
        </strong>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="www" type="button" value="пересчитать">
```

Answer (score 1):

Для выборки по условию можно воспользоваться методом [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), который оставляет в наборе только те элементы, которые удовлетворяют условию:

```
$('#account_calcLayoutGrid12 .row ').find('[class^="col-"]').filter((_, el)=> $(el).find('input').val() > 0);
```

Comment: что-то с filter не работает https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/y9juet5c/

Comment: @spoon100500, там ошибка была: _Uncaught TypeError: el.find is not a function_ - `el` - это html элемент, у него нет find, я забыл его обернуть в jquery, поправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое работает.